# Separate string at upper case letters using StringReplace

Tags: string-manipulation, replacement

Is there a way to turn `AbcDefGhi` into `Abc Def Ghi` by using `StringReplace`? The following pattern does not work:

```
StringReplace[
    "AbcDefGhi",
    (s__) ~~ (t_?UpperCaseQ) ~~ (u_) :> (s <> " " <> t <> u)
]

(* Out: AbcDef Ghi *)
```

Nor do close friends of that pattern that I have tried.

I can do it with a recursive function, but I feel it should be possible with `StringReplace` as well.

Comment: What would you want the output for a string like ""AbcDefGHij"" to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wrap your *before* and *after* patterns with [`Shortest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shortest.html), it gets what you want,

```
sr = 
  StringReplace[
   Except[StartOfString, Shortest[(s___)]] ~~ (t_?UpperCaseQ) ~~ 
     Shortest[(u___)] :> (s <> " " <> t <> u)];
sr /@ {"DistrictOfColumbia", "AbcDefGHij"}
(* {"District Of Columbia", "Abc Def G Hij"} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `Shortest`! Your solution certainly works for `AbcDefGhi`, but not for `DistrictOfColumbia`. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: So in that case, the "f" in "Of" is matching as the lowercase letter after an uppercase letter.  Therefore it won't also match as the lowercase letter before "Columbia".  The key now is to use `s___` instead of `s__`

Answer (score 9):

Simply use the pattern `Except[WordBoundary, t_?UpperCaseQ]` as the pattern to be replaced:

```
sR = StringReplace[Except[WordBoundary, t_?UpperCaseQ] :> " " <> t];

sR["AbcDefGhi"]
```

> "Abc Def Ghi"

```
sR["DistrictOfColumbia"]
```

> "District Of Columbia"

```
sR["A B C"]
"A B C"
```

Comment: When I execute your code with the third example, I get double spaces...

Comment: @Henrik, changing  `StartOfString `to `WordBoundary` seems to fix the issue.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher and kglr I ignored it too but OP didn't ask about anything more than `LetterCharacter..`

Answer (score 8):

What about?:

```
StringTrim @ StringReplace["AbcDefGhi", t_?UpperCaseQ :> " " <> t]
```

Answer (score 7):

How about using `StringSplit` in combination with `Riffle`?

```
f[x_String] := StringJoin[Riffle[StringSplit[x, s_?UpperCaseQ :> s], {"", " "}]];

f["AbcDefGhi"]
f["DistrictOfColumbia"]
```

> "Abc Def Ghi"
>
> "District Of Columbia"

Unfortunately, it also does

```
f["A B C"]
```

> "A  B  C"

So maybe this comes closer to your requirements:

```
g = StringReplace[
   RuleDelayed[
    Repeated[s : Except[WhitespaceCharacter]] ~~ (t__?UpperCaseQ),
    StringRiffle[Join[{s}, Characters[t]]]
    ]
   ];
g["AbcDefGhiAAA"]
g["DistrictOfColumbia"]

g["AbcDefGhi"]
g["DistrictOfColumbia"]
g["A B C"]
```

> ""Abc Def Ghi A A A""
>
> "District Of Columbia"
>
> "A B C"

Note that without `s : Except[WhitespaceCharacter]`, the latter would have been `"A  B  C"`.

Comment: This certainly returns the correct result too. I was just curious about doing it purely with `StringReplace`.

Comment: By the way, your `g[x_]` function fits my criteria and is even simpler.

Comment: @Shredderroy, it's often a good idea to wait before accepting an answer.  Feel free to change your accepted answer if you would like to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses `RegularExpression` to match any upper case letter that is preceded by a non-whitespace character:

```
f = StringReplace[RegularExpression["(?<=\\S)(\\p{Lu})"] :> " $1"];
```

So then:

```
{"AbcDefGhi", "XAbcXDefXGhiXXX", "ABCDEFG", "A B C", "WithPowerComesGreatInscrutability"} //
Map[InputForm @* f] //
Column

(*
  "Abc Def Ghi"
  "X Abc X Def X Ghi X X X"
  "A B C D E F G"
  "A B C"
  "With Power Comes Great Inscrutability"
*)
```

Comment: I think that WL string patterns could use some `LookAhead` and `LookBehind` operators.